# import kml in qgis : kml.kml is not a valid or recognized data source

Tags: qgis, kml

When I import kml.kml (generated from ArcGIS) into Google Earth, there is no problem.

However, when I try importing this file as vector layer in QGIS 1.8 on XUbuntu 12.04, I get this error :

kml.kml is not a valid or recognized data source

I need help to resolve this problem.

Comment: have yout tried to validate the file? (http://kmlvalidator.com/home.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Qgis does not like kml folders with mixed geometry types (points, lines and polygons). Try to separate them in individual folders. Each folder will be represented by a layer in qgis.

Answer (score 2):

when your file works well with google earth, export from google earth with a different file-name and try to import this new kml into qgis

Answer (score 2):

Opening the file in Google Earth and saving again (right click the layer > Save Place as > KML) has solved some of my problems with KMLs.

Comment: Hi Gui, Welcome to GIS.se :) I hope your time here is fruitful and look forward to reading your contributions. However for this one the same answer has already been provided (http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/32953)